# Scrolling content programmatically over time NOT instantly

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been trying to find a way to scroll a page to the bottom in a natural manner in Angular 4. There is an initial block of content that may or may not extend out of the viewport, then content is added dynamically at random intervals. Content should be scrolled to the BOTTOM on initial load and then after the addition of any content.

In ionic it is simple, this will scroll to the bottom over 300ms

```
 @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

 this.content.scrollToBottom(300)
```

Content also provides all current dimensions

```
dimensions = this.content.getContentDimensions()
```

Then all the current dimensions are accessible via the dimensions reference

```
this.dimensions.scrollTop
this.dimensions.contentHeight
this.dimensions.scrollHeight
```

Plus many others the documentation is here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/

I could not find anything to provide the same kind of accessibility in Angular.

So I constructed my own solution based off various posts. My solution uses ElementRef and rxjs. I feel like there should be a better way (which eludes me) to achieve the same result!

My current solution:
I created a reference to the element using ElementRef and Observable.interval() to adjust scrollTop.

In the .html

```
<div #scrollMe>
    //lots of content here that is dynamically added  
</div>
```

In .ts

```
@ViewChild('scrollMe') scrollMe: ElementRef;

scrollBottom() { 
//check if the user has scrollup manually and if they have DON'T scrollBottom
if ( window.pageYOffset + window.outerHeight +
     this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollTop >
     this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollHeight - 300
   ) 
{//Use interval() as a timed iterator
  let myObservable = Observable.interval(20)
  myObservable.takeWhile((data) =>
    //only run while the scroll position is not equal to the scroll height 
    window.pageYOffset + 
    window.outerHeight + 
    this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollTop <
    this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
       .subscribe((output) => {
           //adjust scrollTop by the output amount
           this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollTop = 
           this.scrollMe.nativeElement.scrollTop + output
  })
}
```

The interval emits a sequential stream of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4..... 
Which is used to scroll the page so if there is only a short scroll it will
appear smooth, and if there is a large scroll it start smooth then accelerate so the user doesn't have to wait.

Is there a better option to do this?